# How to split x y columns horizontally into multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, coordinates

I need to split x(42 points)  column and  y(42 points) column into x1, y1,x2,y2,x3,y3..etc columns.
Is there a package or functions can do that?

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag and  in particular provide a minimal (cut down the problem to a smaller one) reproducible (so anyone can copy and paste the input to their session) example using `dput` and also show the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your x and y are the same type you could use a transform.
This would be a base R approach which is quite fast.

```r
# make data
df <- data.frame(x=1:42,y=43:84)

# transform data
df <- as.data.frame(t(as.vector(t(df))))

# add names to columns
names(df) <- paste0(c("x_", "y_"),rep(x = 1:42, each=2))
df
```

Comment: I added a photo of how the data looks like and the expected.Thanks

Comment: Ok. But what is the output supposed to look like? A separate `data.frame` with one row?
It might also be good to follow the suggestion by G. Grothendieck concerning `dput`.

Comment: @departhier yes, exactly. Another dataframe. Actually, I do not know how to do the deput.

Comment: you can generate a `data.frame` called for example `df` in R and then use `dput(df)`. The output of the function is something you can copy paste to your question.

Comment: I edited the answer based on your image

Comment: how to make the code stop at 42 and then make a new row with 42 points. I mean if I have a column with 126 observations, how to make them three rows each with 42.Thanks

Comment: I guess that depends on the relation of the rows to each other. I guess you would have to ask this question with a dataset provided so that it is clear what you have and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tidyr` packages `pivot_wider` function such as below:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y)

df$row_name <- row_names(df) # this adds a dummy variable for each row in df.

tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = row_name, values_from = c(x, y)
```

You will likely need to do some tidying of the column order to get exactly `x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, ...`  however.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#example df
df <- tibble(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=list(c(2, 3), c(4, 5), c(6, 7)))

df %>% unnest(b) %>% 
   group_by(a) %>% 
   mutate(col=seq_along(a)) %>% #add a column indicator
   spread(key=col, value=b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  # cast `x` and `y` into long format:
  pivot_longer(c(x,y)) %>%
  # to each `name`...
  group_by(name) %>%
  # ... add the row number:
  mutate(name = str_c(name, row_number())) %>%
  # cast in wide format:
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) 
# A tibble: 1 × 84
      x1    y1     x2    y2    x3    y3     x4    y4    x5     y5    x6     y6    x7    y7    x8      y8     x9    y9    x10     y10   x11
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 -0.560 -1.27 -0.230  2.17  1.56  1.21 0.0705 -1.12 0.129 -0.403  1.72 -0.467 0.461 0.780 -1.27 -0.0834 -0.687 0.253 -0.446 -0.0285  1.22
# … with 63 more variables: y11 <dbl>, x12 <dbl>, y12 <dbl>, x13 <dbl>, y13 <dbl>, x14 <dbl>, y14 <dbl>, x15 <dbl>, y15 <dbl>, x16 <dbl>,
#   y16 <dbl>, x17 <dbl>, y17 <dbl>, x18 <dbl>, y18 <dbl>, x19 <dbl>, y19 <dbl>, x20 <dbl>, y20 <dbl>, x21 <dbl>, y21 <dbl>, x22 <dbl>,
#   y22 <dbl>, x23 <dbl>, y23 <dbl>, x24 <dbl>, y24 <dbl>, x25 <dbl>, y25 <dbl>, x26 <dbl>, y26 <dbl>, x27 <dbl>, y27 <dbl>, x28 <dbl>,
#   y28 <dbl>, x29 <dbl>, y29 <dbl>, x30 <dbl>, y30 <dbl>, x31 <dbl>, y31 <dbl>, x32 <dbl>, y32 <dbl>, x33 <dbl>, y33 <dbl>, x34 <dbl>,
#   y34 <dbl>, x35 <dbl>, y35 <dbl>, x36 <dbl>, y36 <dbl>, x37 <dbl>, y37 <dbl>, x38 <dbl>, y38 <dbl>, x39 <dbl>, y39 <dbl>, x40 <dbl>,
#   y40 <dbl>, x41 <dbl>, y41 <dbl>, x42 <dbl>, y42 <dbl>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = as.numeric(rnorm(42)),
  y = rnorm(42)
)
```